# App not installed, when sends to compatible versions

Tags: android

I have the application that has '16' mini sdk and '27' targeted sdk versions. When I install the application with USB cable from android studio, it works fine. But when I send the application to other phones b/n 16-27 sdk versions, It appear

> App not installed

error on the phone. I had used xender to send the application.

My sdk versions are here : [image]

Comment: Which APK you send? I mean you send the apk generated after pushing the "play button" in Android studio or using Build->Build APK(s) or Generate Signed APK or from command line?

Comment: first. Determine whether the phone has been installed. if have ,you should uninstall ，then try install agagin.

Comment: I already build the apk and I just run & install  the apk from android studio to my lollipop phone through USB cable, then I get the apk in my phone and I sent to other phones through xender to compatible sdk version phone.After that when I install the apk on receiver phone it appear App not installed problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes App not installed occurs when a same version of the app already exists.

1. Either increment the `versionCode` of the app or **uninstall** the
   previous app.
2. After that, create a signed apk using

---

> **Build->
>           Clean Project** followed by **Build->
>           Generate Signed APK**

---

After looking at the **screenshot** (build.gradle) you shared here, I might advice to put `versionCode` after `versionName`. That way, you don't have to bother about what `versionCode` is written in *AndroidManifest.xml*.

Comment: It worked fine now by your suggestion ,I was not assign versionCode and generate signed APK.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment the problem is that you are using a build built by Android Studio.  
Android Studio will add a `testOnly` attribute so that's why you can't install it on other devices by default.

You need to send a build built by Build -> Build APK(s) or Build -> Generate Signed APK to be able to install it on devices.

Comment: I think I have to used generate signed APK to pubish my APK to play store or other site. Is that?

Comment: Are you asking me? And yes for play store you probably used the generate signed APK. But that is not relevant here since you described a whole different process for distributing your APK to another phone

Comment: Yah I had asked you. Thank you for your suggestion but if I used generate signed apk, can I send my apk to the phones from my pc ? before I publish to play store. My understanding about generate signed apk is only used for to publish play store.

Comment: Yes you can send it at least to your locally connected device. After that you can use that tool you mentioned (xender) to send it further. Please read about the adb command and how to use it. For beta testing i would suggest to use Fabric's Beta.

Comment: I had tried but it is not work. Even I sent to my phone from my pc the released app and I tried to install  but still there is error  message "App not installed" .

Comment: In the logcat you should see a message coming from PackageManager if I am not mistaken and that will tell you why it is not installed.

Comment: When I click the logcat, there is no message. Is I show the error in logcat in running process the apk ?

Comment: In the logcat on the right side where it says show selected application, you can change it to No filter then you can see all the device logs

Comment: No it's fine in the build.gradle. I think we reached the threshold where you need to open new questions for each of your problem. This is getting out of hand. Also I suggest to read/study a basic android development guide because clearly you are missing the basic knowledge you need